# Problems at validating form using MUI5 and Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup, formik-material-ui

I am new to Material UI and I'm trying to learn creating small elements.
I have created in React a form using MUI5 and I want to validate it using Formik and Yup and I encountered a problem: if I open the dropdown country list, but I'm not selecting anything and then I click on another field, the helper text is not showing up. If then I click on yet another field, the helper text is showing up, but the text color is grey and not red and so is the border of the dropdown field.
So, my questions is how can I make the dropdown behave like the other fields?

Here is my code:

```
import {
      Button,
      FormControl,
      FormHelperText,
      InputLabel,
      MenuItem,
      Select,
      TextField,
    } from "@mui/material";
    import { useFormik } from "formik";
    import * as Yup from "yup";

const countries = [
  { id: 1, country_name: "United States" },
  { id: 2, country_name: "China" },
  { id: 3, country_name: "India" },
];

const TestFormik = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      country: "",
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      firstName: Yup.string()
        .max(15, "Must be 15 characters or less")
        .required("Required"),
      lastName: Yup.string()
        .max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less")
        .required("Required"),
      email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email address").required("Required"),
      country: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    }),
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });
  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        required
        fullWidth
        id="firstName"
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        label="First Name"
        margin="normal"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.firstName}
        error={!!formik.touched.firstName && !!formik.errors.firstName}
        helperText={formik.touched.firstName && formik.errors.firstName}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        fullWidth
        id="lastName"
        type="text"
        name="lastName"
        label="Last Name"
        margin="normal"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.lastName}
        error={!!formik.touched.lastName && !!formik.errors.lastName}
        helperText={formik.touched.lastName && formik.errors.lastName}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        fullWidth
        id="email"
        type="email"
        name="email"
        label="Email"
        margin="normal"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.email}
        error={!!formik.touched.email && !!formik.errors.email}
        helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
      />
      <FormControl required fullWidth margin="normal">
        <InputLabel>Country</InputLabel>
        <Select
          label="Country"
          id="country"
          name="country"
          value={formik.values.country}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        >
          {countries?.map((country, i) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={i} value={country.country_name}>
                {country.country_name}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText>
          {formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
      <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default TestFormik;
```

Thanks!